# IOS server spoof

Tags: ios, iphone

Every time you try to downgrade an ios ipsw in itunes or any program it checks if the ios is still being signed by apple through their servers and proceeds. If not it is rejected. I was wondering if it was possible to change the server that the program using to check to a custom spoofed one to trick the program to think the ipsw is still being signed?

Comment: Theoretically: maybe, practically: somwhere between difficult and impossible. iTunes probably talks to the server via https, maybe with certificate pinning, then you would need to change the itunes source, remove the server check, recompile and even then there is a good chance that will not work because now your iTunes application is no longer properly signed which might cause your OS / iPhone to reject anything it does, etc.

Comment: And if the singing information is passed along to the iPhone then it will not accept any non-signed data, which makes it impossible to spoof it without e.g. jailbreaking your iPhone.